# how to calculate relative contribution from standard beta estimate and how to interpret it?

Tags: regression, importance

I have to find out the relative contribution of factors(variables) that i used in my regression(Multiple regression) equation. Currently my approach to find out relative contribution is that i take standard beta estimate of a variable divided by sum of all the standard beta estimates of all the variables included in my model. Problem we are facing with this approach is that we have sum of all beta estimates(resultant sum) becoming negative. if we have a negative estimate for a variable, then dividing this number by resultant sum the relative contribution of that variable becomes positive. we are finding it difficult to interpret it because the variable is inversely related but having positive relative contribution. Is there any easy approach for this problem, if not this?